# Where is the power button on the 2016 MBP With TouchBar?

Tags: macbook-pro

Where is the power button on the 2016 Macbook Pros w/ Touchbar?

Comment: I have the new MacBook Pro, and the power button is the same button as the digital fingerprint reader. You just have to press this button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apple Support Document, [How to turn on or turn off your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201150):

> The power button is adjacent to the Touch Bar and integrated with the Touch ID sensor. Press Touch ID (power button) to turn on (or off) your Mac.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to hold it and force-power-off my machine. I just want to make it sleep like I used to with the old button.